# In torch / nn, how to use nn.View(-1):setNumInputDims(2) with a minibatch 4D tensor?

Tags: lua, neural-network, torch

I am writing a neural network with torch nn.

As part of it I have to transform a 3D tensor with dimensions `a x b x c` into a 2D tensor with dimensions `a x b*c`.

Here is the code:

```
input = torch.Tensor(a, b, c)  -- Arbitrary 3D tensor
net = nn.Sequential()
net:add(nn.View(-1):setNumInputDims(2))
net:forward(input)
```

Now I want to modify my network so that it can handle minibatches as input. Therefore, I want to transform a 4D tensor with dimensions `d x a x b x c` into a 3D tensor with dimensions `d x a x b*c` where `d` is the number of elements in my minibatch. `d` is known in advance, but the other dimensions aren't.

When I feed a 4D tensor into the network above, I get a 2D tensor `d*a x b*c` out of it. How do I have to modify the network so that it creates a 3D tensor instead as desired?

I have tried different combinations like `nn.View(-1).setNumInputDims(3)`, `nn.View(d, -1).setNumInputDims(2)` and `nn.View(d, -1).setNumInputDims(3)` but none of them created a tensor of the format I wanted.

Comment: `setNumInputDims(input:nDimension()-1)`

Comment: @hjpotter92: This corresponds to `.setNumInputDims(3)` gives me a 2D tensor as well, with dimensions `d x a*b*c`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`nn` seems to be very limited in this case. The best I could find to solve my problem is to create a parallel-like network via. `nn.Concat` and `nn.Select`:

```
local net = nn.Concat(1)
for i=1, d do
  local subNet = nn.Sequential()
  subNet:add(nn.Select(1, i))
  subNet:add(nn.View(-1):setNumInputDims(2))
  subNet:add(nn.Replicate(1, 1))
  net:add(subNet)
end
```

Note: You really need `nn.Replicate` in this case, otherwise it will create a `d*a x b*c` tensor as well.

P.S. If someone can provide a better solution (preferably without splitting), I will give him or her the accepted answer marking.

Answer (score 0):

My idea is to transpose 2nd dim into 1st dim, and reshape has an optional boolean argument to take care of the unknown dimension. Hacky but seems working.
    nn.Transpose({1, 2})
    nn.Reshape(d, -1, true)
    nn.Transpose({1, 2})